# List limit 1000, is that a legacy limit?

Tags: apex, governorlimits

I have seen some existing code in my org that divides lists into 1000 each in size and then use apex:repeat and apex:datatable to output them in the visualforce page, which eventually will be transferred into an excel file.

I searched about the governor limit and didn't see such a limit on list size. But obviously the original author did this on purpose. Is there something I am missing here or should I feel safe to remove such logic?

Comment: [Limits for apex:reapt](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_vf.htm)

Comment: @RohitMourya It seems to be an answer to me and resolved my issue

Comment: Yes. I've posted it as answer in more detailed manner.

Comment: Yes, but if you want to display more then 1000 items on VF page . You can use list<list<sObject>> on controller side and repeat inside repeat on VF page  to iterate the list<list<sObject>>.

Comment: See also: [Maximum number of collection items that can be iterated in an iteration component limit in salesforce](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/116092/2995)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll post it as a answer because it would easier for other OP's to get it quickly instead of posting another duplicate question.
As per standard documentation of Salesforce, the governor Limit for `<apex:repeat>` tag is 1000. That means you can't process list on Visualforce page having having size **greater than 1000**.

> Maximum collection items that can be iterated in an iteration component such as  `<apex:pageBlockTable>` and `<apex:repeat>` is 1000

Also for **Read Only** mode one can process records upto **10000**

> Maximum collection items that can be iterated in an iteration component such as `<apex:pageBlockTable>` and `<apex:repeat>` in read-only mode is 10000

More details about **Governor limits** can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_vf.htm)

Comment: You can use a Map to work around this limit, as explained in [this question from 2016](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/116092/maximum-number-of-collection-items-that-can-be-iterated-in-an-iteration-componen) (almost exactly 1 year ago). It feels really hack-ish to me, but the only things limiting you with that approach are viewstate size/ CPU time/ Query rows/ Heap size limits. The only real question you'd need to ask yourself is "why do I want to display so much data at once?" Unless you're generating a csv, even 1000 records is a lot to ask for a person to visually process.

Comment: @DerekF That was a good answer. However OP is trying to export data into excel. So in OP's case that approach might not work.

Comment: Why do you think it might not work? I glossed over the part where OP is eventually getting the data into Excel, but doing that by using Visualforce to generate a CSV file (which is then opened in Excel) is pretty much the only thing I think the Map approach is good for.

Comment: @DerekF we're bound to hit view state at some point because view state also depends on other factors. I think using Chatter to export data is good approach. Recently one of my colleague used it. I don't know how it works but I'll try that approach and post it on some other day.

Comment: If it's just generating a CSV file, you could use the `transient` keyword on the map to keep it out of the viewstate (it'll still be accessible via `{!myPropertyName}`

Comment: @DerekF Yes, We can do that. I just tried Map approach which Adrian has answered. It's really good. Thanks for sharing that link. Learned something new today.