# How to display more than 5000 records in pageblock table with out pagination..?

Tags: apex, visualforce, pageblocktable

On my Visualforce page I've to display more than 5000 records with checkboxes like the following :[image]

Here I'm getting 6781 records, but on my vf page it was displaying 100 records only. If I use PAGINATION then I've to select the records which is belongs to that page only. As per my requirement user can select any of the 6781 accounts at a time. Is there any possible way to display all the records in same vf page with side bar.

Comment: The page will show what your iteration returns so if it is only showing 100 then you will need to check your query/records. As for displaying thousands of records on a page, I would advise against it as no user can manage parsing through thousands of records. not to mention view state. Suggest you look at implementations like http://datatables.net and server side data or javascript remoting etc based on your requirements

Comment: You should really strongly reconsider any requirement that asks you to display more than 1000 records in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see a deeper discussion here: [Maximum number of collection items that can be iterated in an iteration component limit in salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/116092/2995)

The basic idea is that a `Map` allows you to iterate basically as many components as you want. View state is still an issue, and I think the requirement to view so many records is completely ridiculous. But it is technically feasible.

In your controller, us a `Map<Id, SObject>`, or `Map<Id, SomeWrapper>`, as you like:

```
public Map<Id, Wrapper> wrappers { get; private set; }
```

Then on your page you should be able to loop over all of the records:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrappers}" var="wrapper">
    <apex:column>
        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!wrapper.isSelected}" />
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column value="{!wrapper.record.SomeField__c}" />
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

You'll lose the ability to control order if you take this approach.

Answer (score 2):

I had a requirement once to load and display thousands of rows to the user without pagination in a Visualforce Page. I also had to have a checkbox for each row and the "select all" functionality, exactly like you. It was a crazy requirement, but I managed to give them what they wanted in the end.

The way I resolved this was by incorporating AngularJS into the VF page and utilizing a directive called `infinite-scroll` that you can find [here](https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/).

I would load all row data into JavaScript variable so that I could bind the Angular controller to it. The page would initially render only 200 rows, I believe, and then, whenever the user would scroll down the page the `infinite-scroll` directive would load another 20 rows, so the user wouldn't even notice that not all rows were loaded at once.

Of course, the page contained a `filter` functionality at the top (also using Angular), so users were able to filter out the rows, and not scroll down into the abyss to find the desired row.

Also, the `select all` checkbox was bound to a function that would iterate through all the rows in the model and change the `isSelect` field to `true` or `false`.

That's the way I solved this, I hope this will give you some ideas.

Comment: Can you share me thae code which you implented for you requirement for my reference.

Comment: I don't have the code with me atm, but it shouldn't be too hard for you to implement this if you try. Just start by adding AngularJS to your page and first try to just render out some rows with it using `ng-repeat` directive. There are lots of Angular tutorials out there. When you get that going, it will be easy to add `infinite-scroll` directive to it.